# @nest/ng-universal without webpack

Tags: typescript, angular, babel, angular-cli, nestjs

Есть ли возможность в модуле @nest/ng-universal заменить Webpack на babel-cli или другой сборщик пакетов? В другом проекте для сборки обходился с помощью babel, но как использовать его в данном случае - не имею представления.

> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
>
> ng new ngnest
>
> cd ngnest
>
> ng add @nestjs/ng-universal

Устанавливает Webpack для сборки серверной части, мои потуги перевести это на babel, убрав webpack не принесли пользы.

Comment: Я никогда не использовать бабель, но ни разу ни от кого не слышал, чтоб вебпак пытались ним заменить, обычно их использовали вместе. Во-вторых сам юниверсал из коробки заточен под вебкап (и даже nest/ng-universal заточен под вебпак, если посмотреть исходный код). В 3х банальный вопрос - зачем тебе это?

Comment: @overthesanity попытка подключить к nest модуль @nest/graphql заканчивается тем, что build:ssr начинает падать с ошибками сборки.
если быть точнее - Can't reexport the named export 'visitWithTypeInfo' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available) и ей подобные, только названия модулей меняются.
В истории issue есть заметка об этом, автор сам указал, что webpack не может собрать некоторые пакеты Nodejs сходу. (Unfortunately, some Node.js packages cannot be easily bundled using Webpack.)

Comment: @overthesanity

При использовании костыля, указанным автором начинают лететь ошибки вида " Can't resolve '@nestjs/websockets/socket-module' in 'D:\WebDevelopment\ngnest\node_modules\@nestjs\core' "

Допустим, что мы пользуемся данным костылём и вписываем модули, на которые он ругается в LazyImport. Вроде всё нормально, все собралось.

Запускаем npm run serve:ssr и видим ошибки

Unhandled Promise rejection: Unknown type "Query". ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Unknown type "Query";

Comment: @overthesanity
Ну и предупреждение

(node:1500) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.

Какой сборщик вместо babel посоветуете?